# Programmatically add new row to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rows

I'm trying to add new rows to a DataGrid on a WPF application when clicking on a specific button.
This is what I tried so far:

```
DataGridRow row = new DataGridRow();
table.Items.Add(row); // table = my DataGrid
```

When I run this code, it throws a `System.ArgumentNullException` saying

> Value cannot be null

What should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should really be bound...

Comment: Add a data item to the collection the grid is bound to

Comment: Agreed you are thinking about tightly coupled Views, change your thinking to views with templates that automatically create rows base on the collection items do not add explicit rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your Data Grid's `ItemsSource` property to a collection of POCO objects and instead of adding Data Grid rows add new POCO objects to that collection and your "problem" will be automagically resolved...

This assumes change notification of your VM properties and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your POCO classes of course...